# How do you achieve the same Owned, Borrowed functionality as Cow

Tags: rust

How do you create a Cow that never clones? I am looking for the same functionality but I don't actually want to clone.

I need the { Borrowed, Owned } enum that conveniently references a reference or gets the owned object. But I want to ensure it is never cloned.

Answer (score 2):

Part of `Cow`'s functionality is in the name: "copy-on-write." Cloning is part of the base functionality.

You can always trivially implement your own such enum if you want to avoid the `ToOwned` requirement:

```
enum OwnedOrBorrowed<'a, T> {
    Borrowed(&'a T),
    Owned(T),
}

impl<'a, T> std::ops::Deref for OwnedOrBorrowed<'a, T> {
    type Target = T;
    
    fn deref(&self) -> &T {
        match self {
            Self::Borrowed(v) => v,
            Self::Owned(v) => &v,
        }
    }
}

impl<'a, T> std::convert::AsRef<T> for OwnedOrBorrowed<'a, T> {
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &T {
        self
    }
}
```

You can implement any other traits you might need as well.  (Unfortunately, this can be a lot of boilerplate, though you can reduce it somewhat with macros.)

Comment: You could also bound the impl on `Borrow` that way it would work on a wider variety of types e.g. the version of `OwnedOrBorrowed` here would not work for the pair `String/&str` (and more generally smart pointers), whereas `Cow` does.

Comment: @Masklinn Yes, though you would need to specify both types, e.g. `OwnedOrBorrowed<String, str>` since `Borrow` is itself generic. I chose the simpler route over the more flexible but also more unwieldy route.